# What is the appropriate limit for a question in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I am doing my first database project.

I would like to know what is an appropriate limit for questions in length.

My plan has `varchar(5000)` for the length of a question at the moment.

**What is the appropriate limit for a question in a database?**

[edit]

A question in the database is like a question here in SO, with code formatting.

Comment: Are you going to allow people to include code snippets, or sections of dialog? Will there be formatting characters?

Comment: Could you clarify on what type of question it is?

Comment: It is less a database question and more an application question.  How large do you want to questions to be?  I would bet that questions over a couple thousand characters quickly become too large and complicated.

Comment: It is very, very amusing to watch people (six so far) flailing at a question that is too incoherent to support an answer.  And then the answers get voted on!

Comment: wtf? where does it say they are using sql server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nvarchar(max) sql server 2005

Answer (score 3):

Which DBMS are you using? You'll probably want to use a TEXT column or equivalent, which is much better for storing large amounts of data.

Comment: We have little information, but whatever is meant by "question," I do not think a text entry is the subject.

Comment: Provided these questions can be fairly long (if you'll notice, some StackOverflow questions are well into the thousands of characters), I don't think that text is out of the question. Ha.

Answer (score 2):

Can the questions be quite long?  Perhaps `varchar(max)` would be the best choice. (This is assuming that you are using SQL Server of course.)

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own limit if you are also designing the app for question input. For example think of Twitter's limit to 140 characters or less. You could do the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, this is not a database question but an application question? How big do you need the field to be to store your questions?

However, the one thing that's almost certainly a bad idea is using VARCHAR for things like questions which contain natural text. This only supports the basic US-ASCII character set which is very likely not what you want. I'd suggest you use NVARCHAR instead which supports the full range of international characters.

If you need a short field (say a few hundred characters at most) then it would be reasonable to use a field with a specified maximum length, e.g. NVARCHAR(256), however if it's a lot of text (as can appear on this site) then NVARCHAR(MAX) is probably more appropriate. Note that in later versions of SQL Server, the NTEXT type is essentially deprecated.

Comment: IIRC, the maximum length for nvarchar(max) in SQL Server 2005 would be 4000 characters.

Comment: @kevinw - Um, no, the maximum length for NVARCHAR(MAX) is about 1,000,000,000 characters as the max field size is 2GB and it uses 2 bytes per character.

Comment: @Greg Beech - apologies - my figure is for nvarchar rather than nvarchar(max) (remembering the number comes from too much time ensuring a database schema would still work in 2000).

Answer (score 0):

A question or an answer?

Also, appropriateness is completely dependent on the application domain.  By this, I mean that if you are doing simple survey's, then the question will probably be less than 500 characters.

Assuming you are building this off of some specs, what does the form look like?

Comment: I'm building a discussion site inspired by SO.

Answer (score 0):

If there truly is no limit, you can use a CLOB (or your local database's equivalent) which allows unlimited text.

Comment: I wonder how safe that would be in practice, or is it better practice to limit the size before getting to the db?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your other questions indicate that you are using PostgreSQL. If you are, then the [PostgreSQL documentation on data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html) has a good discussion of the different types available and when it is appropriate to use each. In particular, note that "nvarchar" is not the name of a PostgreSQL data type.